# Parse a empty string into SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

So, so far I have this:

```
static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
jDateChooser8 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
```

when I parse the right date let's say this one:

```
jDateChooser8.setDate(df.parse("24 07 1987"));
```

it's ok, but when I try to parse  `""` (empty string)

```
jDateChooser8.setDate(df.parse(""));
```

I get an exeption:

first line of error is:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
```

all I want to do is set date to `""`, how to do it?

Comment: What outcome would you expect? The empty string is not a date, so what do you mean with 'set the date to "" ' ?

Comment: Is your actual question how to clear out a `com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser`.

Comment: no, I want to set date to a jdateChooser to be empty.

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc for [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) states: "Throws:
    ParseException - if the beginning of the specified string cannot be parsed."

The string `""` cannot be parsed, and thus a `ParseException` is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

i did what i want with seems it worked.

```
jDateChooser8.cleanup();
```