# Passing empty String to the server

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to avoid passing the `null` value returned by the server so that `invalid date` isn't shown on front end. I am referring to the following code :

```
//var value_ = "2017-06-09 10:05:21.0"

var value_ = null;

if(moment(value_).isValid()){
                        alert(moment(value_).format('MM/DD/YYYY'));

                       }
                       else  {
                        alert("Display Empty String:"+"");
                       }
```

[JSFiddle here:](http://jsfiddle.net/ns1824ew/)

So, passing empty string `" "` works well from the UI point of view and I don't see `invalid dates` for dates which have `null` values. When I pass the empty string to the server`" "`, I get an error similar to the one someone is facing here which is obvious because I am passing empty string:

[parse a emty string into SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541698/parse-a-emty-string-into-simpledateformat)

Is there a way to overcome this from UI point of view so that I don't see `invalid date` option just like it's shown in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/md0wu0d1/1/) ?

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to get, `moment("")` gives an `Invalid date` as you showed in first fiddle, if you want to avoid it you can use the code of the second fiddle.

Comment: @VincenzoC When I use my second fiddle, I am basically sending empty strings to my database `" "` and in that case, I am getting  PaseException from Java side. I am wondering how can I avoid sending an empty string to the database and also avoid showing `invalid date` on the UI side? 2) Also wondering, is there a way I can use `moment` which will avoid displaying `invalid date`. Because in my second fiddle, I had to completely get rid of moment to get rid of `invalid date` thing.